# Question on Exact sequence

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $$0 \rightarrow A \rightarrow B \rightarrow C\rightarrow 0$$ be an exact sequence, with $f:A \rightarrow B$, and $g: B \rightarrow C$. Let $Q$, $P$ be two submodules of $B$.

I want to determine whether the following fact is true:
$g(Q)=g(P)$ and $f^{-1}(Q)=f^{-1}(P)$, implies $P=Q$.

I am not getting a counterexample. I suppose that it is not true. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let

$$A:=\mathbb{R}, B:=\mathbb{R}^2, C:=\mathbb{R},$$
$$P:=\{(x,0)\;|\; x\in \mathbb{R}\}, Q:=\{(0,x) \; |\;x\in \mathbb{R}\}$$

and define $f,g $ by $f(x)=(x,x), \; g(x,y)=x-y.$

Then the sequence is exact (in $\mathrm{Mod-}\mathbb{R}$), $f^{-1}(P)=f^{-1}(Q)=\{0\}$ and $g(P)=g(Q)=C$, however, $P\neq Q$.

Comment: @ Pravel C.Many Many thanks. How did you think of that. Did you knew it before?

Comment: Well, to be honest, I liked the idea of it being true, started to look for a proof and failed almost instantly. : )

Answer (score 0):

Let $B=\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$.  The map $g$ is projection on the first coordinate.  Then the element $(1,0)$ and the element $(1,1)$ differ by the element $(0,1)$, which generates the kernel.  Also, $f^{-1}(\langle (1,0)\rangle)=f^{-1}(\langle (1,1)\rangle)=\{0\}$.

Comment: @DanielRust Sorry, projection onto the FIRST coordinate.

Comment: @DanielRust But, $\langle (1,0)\rangle\cap \langle (0,1)\rangle=\langle (1,1)\rangle\cap \langle (0,1)\rangle=\{0\}$. So, the $f^{-1}$ are equal.

Comment: Sorry my mistake.